# HTTP Post method for search/filter failing at client side?

Tags: ajax, http

I had an assignment where I need to have a `http POST` method which takes `int start` and `int end` parameters, then searches database and **returns all Cities** with `population` property between the mentioned parameters. Note: I have to use my custom routing for the method.

**CitiesController:**

```
        [Route("api/cities/search")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostSearch(int min, int max)
        {
            var list = db.Cities
                .Where(c => c.Population > min && c.Population < max)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Population);

            return Ok(list);
                
        }
```

This is the part in `script.js` where im calling `.ajax POST` method.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (token) {
        headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
    };
    var min = $("#searchField1").val();
    var max = $("#searchField2").val();
    var url = host + "api/cities/search";
    var sendData = {
        "Min": min,
        "Max": max
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: url,
        data: sendData
    }).done(fillDataSearch)

      .fail(function (data, status) {
            alert("!");
    });
});
```

Once i click the `submit` button in this `#searchForm`, i get **405 STATUS CODE - Method not allowed** Here's what it returns:

```
 <Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
<MessageDetail>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Get(Int32)' in 'Finalni_Kraci.Controllers.CitiesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Based on this, he's targeting `GET` method with **parameter** `int id` (which i do have), but i do not know why.

I tried debugging, everything seems okay until he skips to `.fail` part of $.ajax. I tried testing this with postman, if i put values in `parameteres` it works, but if i try to pass values through `body`

```
{
    "Min": 50000,
    "Max": 300000
}
```

i get 405 Status code again with message: **The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.**

I am not really sure what is the correct way to do it. So far i tried what i provided but i am losing idea of what i am doing wrong. Let me know if i need to provide anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake, i had to use filter `object` as a `parameter` for my server's `POST` method, not two integers.

This is solved.